# If a theorem is true for a sub/super-martingale does it also hold for a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

If a theorem is true for a sub/super-martingale does it also hold for a martingale? Since a sub-martingale has the characterestic property  $\mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal{F}_m] \geq X_m$ (with $m\leq n$) which includes the case of equality and hence also the martingale case?

Comment: since a martingale is a sub and a super martingale...

Comment: So the answer is yes right! But why don't we define it terms of strict inequalities to seperate the cases?

Comment: It's just more elegant to keep them together, usually. Compare "every nonnegative supermartingale converges" to "every nonnegative supermartingale converes, and the same is true for every nonnegative martingale," for instance. It's just cleaner to allow martingales to inherit properties of supermartingales for the purposes of stating and proving theorems. (Also, I claim that the collection of results which apply to strict sub-/super-martingales and **not** to ordinary martingales is mostly a small and unimportant collection of results.)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clearing it up!